# Next.js deployment info during runtime

Tags: next.js

I can't seem to find what would be the best way to pass deployment info to the runtime so that I could read it later on the client by accessing certain route or opening file?

I'm thinking that I could probably write a small script which would generate page and hardcode the needed data before build and deploy script is ran, but that seems really hacky.

I'm wondering if there is a clean way to do that just by passing some config params, etc..?

I tried looking in nextjs docs, the closest that I found is https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/generateBuildId but it's not clear how and whether I can read it at all during runtime?

I.e.:

If I wanted to open `localhost:3000/debug` and see basic info like:

```
Deployed at: 2023-08-01 @ 12:00
Commit: 232j3hg23gh23gh324deedefef
```

Thank you